# To prove that the limit of a bi-variate function is nonexistent at a point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

It has been asked to evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x-y}$$ if it exists at all and otherwise to disprove it.

After much thoughts , I came up with an idea of substituting $y$ with $x-mx^3$ which devolved the limit to $(2/m)$ and thus served my purpose of disproving the existence of a limit.

But, thinking of such half-weird substitutions take some reasonable amount of time; the luxury of which is seldom available at examinations. So, what are  other better methods to disprove the existence of this limit?

Any general algorithm (??) on disproving the existence of bi-variate limits (without indulging into trick-substitutions) will be also appreciated.

Comment: @M.Santos Well, in that case, I need to show the trig function to be unbounded.....Seems tedious and complex:(...... (In response to a now-deleted comment, that mentioned about transformation to polar coordinates.)

Comment: What about $x=y$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael presumably the domain of the function which is having its limit taken does not include points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(x,x)$.

Comment: @Robert Apologies. The domain excludes all points in the form of $(x,x)$.

Comment: Then take $x$ very close to $y$.

Comment: That in a sense, does lead to the result:-)

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric: If you want to ask for a **systematic method** to analyze all such limit expressions, you should state that, and you should also not ask for "better methods to disprove the existence of **this** limit". Otherwise, your question is a duplicate since Git Gud already explained how to find suitable paths. I can think of a general algorithm, but it needs higher-level analysis.

Comment: @user21820 Can I now edit my question to ask  a systematic method to analyze all such limit expressions?

Comment: @WingedBladesofGodric: You can. However, you may not get an answer, because it may be too difficult. In mathematics, many theorems can only be proven by someone guided by enough experience to know what to try. In this case, you can make use of the fact that keeping $x = 0$ must give the same limit if it exists, and so since the limit must be $0$, you can investigate when the fraction stays away from $0$, which leads to letting $y = x+f(x)$ where $f(x) ∈ o(x)$ as $x→0$. This technique can deal with most exercises in school, but still requires experience.

Answer (score -1):

The standard and more effective method to show (by hand calculation) that a limit doesn't exist is to find at least two different paths with different limits as you have done.

Of course we can apply the epsilon-delta method using the same two paths but that way shouldn't be so different form the method you have already used to prove that limit doesn't exist.

Note that with some practice and a good strategy, figure out such "half-weird substitutions" don't take much time and it is indeed a correct an effective method to proceed. For the proper strategy to follow, refer also to the related

- [What is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ (x^2y^2}{(x^3-y^3)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2994152/505767)